# How to create a bean at runtime only on request with specified values at runtime?

Tags: java, spring-boot, runtime, hikaricp, spring-bean

Requirement: In java, I want to configure hikari datasource for more than 1 Oracle database. Each database will have different configuration. So, I wanted to create a hikari datasource which should create a datasource bean with runtime parameters and custom name. These parameter values will come to know at runtime only.
So, in the code there will be a for loop in which I will get database details and based on it I wanted to create a bean with some custom name.

**How to create such beans at runtime on request with custom name and runtime parameters?**